# rest api magento 2 get attribute code by attribute id

Tags: magento2, rest-api, json

I need to get the attribute code by attribute id with rest api.
This is needed for configurable product.
I get the configurable product data:

```
  "extension_attributes": {
        "website_ids": [
            1
        ],
        "configurable_product_options": [
            {
                "id": 2568,
                "attribute_id": "253",
                "label": "Size",
                "position": 0,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value_index": 1847
                    },
                    {
                        "value_index": 1844
                    },
                    {
                        "value_index": 1845
                    }
                ],
                "product_id": 25539
            }
        ],
        "configurable_product_links": [
            25540,
            25541,
            25542
        ]
    },
```

The '`configurable_product_options`' has no `attribute_code`, I need it to find the value of the value_index which is the option id.
How to get the `attribute_code`?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 Provide the rest API to get the product attributes value and its option

you can try this API **catalogProductAttributeRepositoryV1**  and y**ou can pass the attribute_id instead of the attribute_code.**

[image]

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**